# Regular Expression to accept only 0,1,(,),|,&

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that contains only below 6 characters in a string

0,1,(,),|,&

I came up with this regular expression

^[0-1\|()\&]$

But it seems to fail even when valid string is given as input. As below

```
const inputStr = "(0&(1&(1|0))";
const validateStr = new RegExp("^[0-1\|\(\)\&]$");
const isValid = validateStr.test(inputStr);
```

Above need to be returned true, but the output of isValid is false. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: This? `const validateStr = /^[01|&()]+$/i;`

Comment: @ChrisG why not posting as an answer?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Because it is extremely unlikely that anybody else is going to have the same issue, so the halflife of this question is probably going to be kinda short.

Comment: this seems to work! Thanks @ChrisG. But why not without new RegExp... and why not escape the special characters like |&()

Comment: @gregchap JS recognizes regular expressions, and you don't need to escape characters inside a Character set delimited by `[ ]`.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the clarification. If you add as an answer I will accept it. I cannot upvote your comments too, since low reputation.

Comment: don't you also have to check if the expression is valid by matching for example the number of opening and closing parentheses. `alert(eval("(0&(1&(1|0))"))` results in error, but `alert(eval("(0&(1&(1|0)))"))` in 0

Comment: @Slai at the moment that is not a concern...But I would appreciate it if you can suggest something to check for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a plus after your character set to search the whole string!

```js
const inputStr = "(0&(1&(1|0))";
const validateStr = new RegExp(/^[0-1()|&]+$/);
const isValid = validateStr.test(inputStr);
console.log(isValid);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! But @ChrisG has already answered in the comments above. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @greg chap no problem